# Is it possible to make cross browser rendering site without using CSS reset?

Tags: html, css

- Is it possible to make cross browser
  rendering site without using CSS
  reset?
- Is CSS Reset for all website, small,
  one page, big?
- Should we use write all css without
  reset then only solve needed
  rendering problems nad only keep
  needed things in CSS Reset, or we
  should use CSS Reset from starting
  point?

Should i suggest to use CSS reset to new CSS HTML learner or not? I was thinking if i would suggest to use CSS reset then how he will know why we use CSS Reset. am i right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- **Is it possible to make cross browser rendering site without using CSS reset?**

  It's definitely possible to make sites that render similarly across browsers, but very difficult, *whether with a CSS reset or not*, to make them render pixel-for-pixel the same across all browsers (personally I don't try that hard unless a client demands I do so). But for most cases, it's doable.
- **Is CSS Reset for all websites (small, one page, big)?**

  I've used my own CSS reset for my entire web site as well as single-page side projects. I don't really think it's the size that matters, but again that's just my own opinion. If you want to, you can always make your custom resets simpler for smaller sites, if browser anomalies aren't a big issue.
- **Should we use write all CSS without reset then only solve needed rendering problems and only keep needed things in CSS Reset, or should we use CSS Reset from starting point?**

  The point of a CSS reset is not as much to solve rendering problems in individual browsers as it is to strip all *default* browser styles, whether they're problematic or not, and start from a clean slate. To that end, a CSS reset is mostly meant to be used as a starting point.
- **Should I suggest to use CSS reset to new CSS/HTML learners or not? I was thinking if I would suggest to use CSS reset then how he will know why we use CSS Reset.**

  Sure, why not? I think it's great if we share to CSS beginners about the differences in the ways browsers render things by default. As a starter I was also really confused by why Firefox 2 and older chose a default body font of `sans-serif` instead of `serif`, while other browsers chose `serif`. By using a CSS reset we can save beginners time that they'd otherwise spend trying to work their way around browser defaults.

Comment: if you don't you will end up making one in your default styles anyways. if its http requests you care about here i would just include the reset in the default style sheet.

Comment: @Thorn007: Actually, that's what I do. I think it's silly to place a reset in its own CSS file.

Comment: +1 I've edited my question. pls give ur view on last point also. Thanks

Comment: my point in last question is if in learning i suggest CSS reset to beginner then how he will know why we use CSS Reset. I was thinking i would introduce CSS Reset to him after some struggling of him with rendering differences.

Comment: Yes, I think that's a better way to go. I also struggled with differences first before getting to know resets.

Answer (score 2):

Answering the questions, there is no way to *reset* all browser's default style by a simple command but CSS Reset.

Obviously the use of the CSS Reset are conditioned by your personal choice, I use to avoid CSS Resetting for simple tableless layouts. Complex layouts like DeviantArt for example could be a good idea to reset all styles.

**But the most important point is:** Whatever your choice (both are good), do not reset properties that you will not use, and consider to keep your CSS Reset in the same file to save HTTP requests.

It keeps your CSS maintainability for the future.

Comment: If you're only reseting properties that you use, doesn't that defeat the purpose of the reset in the first place? (honest question, I'm not a web developer)

Comment: You are right, just complementing: The properties that you are using AND properties that AFFECT your property of interest.